# Magento getParam v $_GET

Tags: php, magento

Can anyone explain the differences both functionally and in terms of good/bad practice whhy one of these should be preferred over the other:

```
$getParam = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('getparam');
```

v

```
$getParam = $_GET['getparam'];
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is a significant difference between the two. `$_GET` is simply an array, like `$_POST`. However, calling `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('param_name')` will give you access to both GET and POST *(DELETE and PUT are not included here)* - see code below:

```
lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php

public function getParam($key, $default = null)
{
    $keyName = (null !== ($alias = $this->getAlias($key))) ? $alias : $key;

    $paramSources = $this->getParamSources();
    if (isset($this->_params[$keyName])) {
        return $this->_params[$keyName];
    } elseif (in_array('_GET', $paramSources) && (isset($_GET[$keyName]))) {
        return $_GET[$keyName];
    } elseif (in_array('_POST', $paramSources) && (isset($_POST[$keyName]))) {
        return $_POST[$keyName];
    }

    return $default;
}
```

In addition, if the system sets other params with `Mage::app()->getRequest()->setParam()`, it becomes accessible via the `getParam()` function. In Magento you want to always use `getParam()`.

Comment: Also gives access to params parsed from the url e.g. site.com/foo/bar/baz/bip/bop/boom/bum would have params bip = bop and boom = bum

Comment: Ah, yes - can't believe I missed that :)

Comment: And what exacly IS a "param", if not a request parameter (part of the url)? Why would you use `setParam()`?

Comment: A param in Magento is a helper for a combined array of the values found in the url, GET and POST variables. I don't see much usage for `setParam()` other than to filter or parse values before they get to the system (in a `predispatch` observer). That isn't something that is used often, but it is helpful when you need it.

Answer (score 6):

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('getparam');
```

Will return you 'getparam' if it is send with GET, POST (not sure about DELETE, PUT ...) request. Did not work with Magento but if there parameters that sent through routing. I would expect them also being accessible through that function.

`$_GET` contains only parameters sent through GET

`$_POST` contains only parameters sent through POST

Comment: `$_GET` contains params from the querystring regardless of request method. `$_POST` contains params from the request body **if** the `Content-Type` header of the request was `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the request method was `POST`

Comment: You can POST Content type json ;)