# Custom form posting "Array" rather than user input values

Tags: php, arrays, forms, foreach, postdata

We are using the Aheadworks Helpdesk Module and are trying to create a second form to capture specific information and use the form to create a ticket where all of the form content gets posted to the "content" section of Helpdesk.

The problem is, if I use the name="content", what gets posted into the "content" section is simply "Array"

The form code is quite simple:

```
<form id="helpdesk-ticket-form" action="../helpdeskultimate/customer/new/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="title" value="WHOLESALE SETUP REQUEST" type="hidden">
<div><label for="title_field">Name<span class="required">*</span></label><br> <input id="title" class="input-text required-entry" style="width: 250px;" name="" value="" type="text"></div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div><label for="title_field">Company Name<span class="required">*</span></label>    <br><input id="content_field" class="input-text " title="Company" name="content" value="" type="text"></div>
<input name="department_id" value="2" type="hidden">
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div><label for="content_field">Message<span class="required">*</span></label><br>     <textarea id="content_field" class="required-entry" style="width: 450px;" name="content" rows="10" cols="53"></textarea></div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div><label for="filename">Attach Reseller Permit (2Mb limit)</label><br> <input id="filename" class="input-file" style="width: 450px;" name="filename" type="file"></div>
<div class="button-set">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="button-set"><span><span><br></span></span></div>
<div class="button-set"><button class="button right form-button" type="submit"><span>  <span>Submit ticket</span></span> </button></div>
</form>
```

I have tried using  name="content[]" but it also returned "Array"

The module looks to be using this post method:

```
public function newAction()
{
    if (!$this->_getCustomerSession()->getCustomerId()) {
        $this->_getCustomerSession()->authenticate($this);
        return;
    }
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
    $customer = $this->_getCustomerSession()->getCustomer();

    $Proto = Mage::getModel('helpdeskultimate/proto');
    $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if (isset($postData['department_id'])) {
        $Proto->setDepartmentId($postData['department_id']);
    }
    try {

        $Proto
                ->setSubject(@$postData['title'])
                ->setContent(@$postData['content'])
                ->setPriority(@$postData['priority'])
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->setFrom(Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->getId())
                ->setSource('web');
```

The insert into the message field seems to come from here:

```
/* Insert */
    try {
        $message->setContent(trim($data['content']));
        $validateResult = $message->validate();
```

The full controller file can be downloaded from http://www.gingabox.com/CustomerController.zip

I am not sure how to actually use a foreach statement with the @$postData['content'], or if there is a better solution.

I would happily ask AheadWorks, but have been told by them that they are not accepting customization inquiries at this time (too busy)...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$this->getRequest()->getPost();` retrieves all of the post data in a single array, does `$this->getRequest()->getPost('content');` also return just the type?

Comment: Thank you Joe.   I am not familiar with the structure, could you point me in the right direction?   Would that replace the @postdata['content'] line?

Comment: Ahh, sorry I think I understand... I changed `$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();` to `$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('content');`  This however causes the ticket to not post any of the input values and returns an error.

Comment: I was unable to find much documentation about the inner workings of helpdesk ultimate, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533936/magento-getparam-v-get) regarding magneto suggests getParam, so maybe try `$this->getRequest()->getParam('content')`.  Failing all else, have you tried `$_POST['content']`?

Comment: Thank you for your help and taking the time to look for a solution.  I tried both of the above.

`$this->getRequest()->getParam('content')` returns an error (missing input data error)
     
`$_POST['content']` posts "Array"

I also tried adding `$_POST = $this->getRequest()->getPost('content');`  to the compliment `$_POST['content']`  and it also gets a missing input error.

Comment: Assuming this is not a production system, you might try putting a couple `print_r` calls or even a `phpinfo` to see if your data is actually getting posted.

Comment: On the form, have you tried setting name to: `name="content[department_id]"`? Then within the php you should be able to set postData to: `$postData = $_REQUEST['content'];`.

Comment: How does your form look like?

Comment: thank you all for your comments and suggestions.   I have tried them with no change in the way that it is posted.   I have added information to the original question, including the form code and a link to the full file.   I am very grateful for all of your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

The word "Array" is what you get when you convert a PHP array into a string; since array values can contain anything, PHP doesn't bother trying to figure out how to convert an array and just returns the string `"Array"`. This is exactly what happens in the line:

```php
// The trim() function casts $data as a string => string(5) "Array"
$message->setContent(trim($data['content']));
```

There are functions that *do* return a string representation of array contents, such as `print_r()`. This will spit out the array in a multiline string, so incorporating that in your code would be:

```php
$message->setContent(print_r($data['content'], TRUE));
```

If you wanted the contents of the array as a single-line string you should probably use a `foreach()` statement like you mentioned in your question. Here's a quick example:

```php
$contentString = 'Second Form values:' . PHP_EOL;
foreach($data['content'] as $key => $value) {
    $contentString .= PHP_EOL . '    ' . $key . ': ' . $value;
}
```

Then you would be able to use `$contentString` as the message instead of accessing the `$data` array value directly. I don't know what the `validate()` method is doing in your example, but it is definitely a good idea to ensure that you are properly escaping the values within this second form before you use them as the body of an email.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I have tried the `print_r()` example and still get "Array", but not sure where I the `foreach()` example would be placed.   Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: The four lines in my `foreach()` example should be placed inside your second `try` block, just above the line where `$message->setContent` happens. Then instead of setting the message with `$data['content']` you would use `$contentString` in its place.

Comment: Thank you for the information!   Unfortunately it still returns "Array".   I set `$message->setContent(print_r($contentString, TRUE));`    Not quite sure where to go from here.  But, thank you again for your help.

Comment: If you are using the `foreach()` construct then you don't need the `print_r()` call in your code. Just use `$message->setContent($contentString);` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the form definition in HTML then maybe you will be able to receive an array as content, please have a look at the following example:

```
<form id="helpdesk-ticket-form" action="tescik.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="title" value="WHOLESALE SETUP REQUEST" type="hidden">
<div><label for="title_field">Name<span class="required">*</span></label><br> <input id="title" class="input-text required-entry" style="width: 250px;" name="content[name]" value="" type="text"></div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div><label for="title_field">Company Name<span class="required">*</span></label>    <br><input id="content_field" class="input-text " title="Company" name="content[company]" value="" type="text"></div>
<input name="department_id" value="2" type="hidden">
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div><label for="content_field">Message<span class="required">*</span></label><br>     <textarea id="content_field" class="required-entry" style="width: 450px;" name="content[message]" rows="10" cols="53"></textarea></div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div><label for="filename">Attach Reseller Permit (2Mb limit)</label><br> <input id="filename" class="input-file" style="width: 450px;" name="filename" type="file"></div>
<div class="button-set">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="button-set"><span><span><br></span></span></div>
<div class="button-set"><button class="button right form-button" type="submit"><span>  <span>Submit ticket</span></span> </button></div>
</form>
```

Please note the changed form names like `content[message]`, `content[company]` etc. This should resolve to an Array of values.